# make can't ld correctly the libssh library with msys2 on Windows 10

Tags: gcc, cmake, msys2, libssh, libnetconf2

I have filed an issue on [libssh git](https://gitlab.com/libssh/libssh-mirror/-/issues/97).
This is an link issue, I'm not sure if it is about libnetconf2 or libssh.

**Environment**: msys2 + mingw64

**OS**: Win10

**Installed packages**: libssh-devel with pacman, version: 0.9.6

```
$ pkg-config --modversion libssh
0.9.6
```

libssh installed location:

```
$ find / -name "*libssh*"
/usr/include/libssh
/usr/include/libssh/libssh.h
/usr/include/libssh/libsshpp.hpp
/usr/include/libssh/libssh_version.h
/usr/lib/cmake/libssh
/usr/lib/cmake/libssh/libssh-config-noconfig.cmake
/usr/lib/cmake/libssh/libssh-config-version.cmake
/usr/lib/cmake/libssh/libssh-config.cmake
/usr/lib/libssh.dll.a
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libssh.pc
```

I'm try to compile the `libnetconf2` with cmake:

1. If just run the `cmake ..` in build folder, the cmake can't find the correct location of libssh:

```
cmake ..
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/libcrypto.dll.a (found version "1.1.1l")
-- OpenSSL found, required for TLS
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.21.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find LibSSH (missing: LIBSSH_LIBRARIES) (Required is at least
  version "0.7.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.21.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  CMakeModules/FindLibSSH.cmake:113 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:239 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

2. You have to run the cmake with some additional flags to generate the right make files:

`cmake -DLIBSSH_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/libssh -DLIBSSH_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/ ..`

3. And then run the make command, which will generate a lot of `undefined reference` to error:

```
[ 53%] Building C object CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/src/session_server.c.o
[ 61%] Building C object CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/src/session_client_ssh.c.o
[ 69%] Building C object CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/src/session_server_ssh.c.o
[ 76%] Building C object CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/src/session_client_tls.c.o
[ 84%] Building C object CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/src/session_server_tls.c.o
[ 92%] Building C object CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/compat/compat.c.o
[100%] Linking C shared library msys-netconf2-2.dll
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/src/io.c.o: in function `nc_read':
/g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/io.c:143: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_channel_read'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/io.c:148: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_get_error'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/io.c:153: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_channel_is_eof'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/src/io.c.o: in function `nc_read_poll':
/g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/io.c:483: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_channel_poll_timeout'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/io.c:485: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_get_error'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/src/io.c.o: in function `nc_session_is_connected':
/g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/io.c:615: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_is_connected'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/src/io.c.o: in function `nc_write':
/g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/io.c:697: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_channel_is_closed'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/io.c:697: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_channel_is_eof'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/io.c:698: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_channel_is_closed'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/io.c:707: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_channel_write'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/src/log.c.o: in function `nc_libssh_thread_verbosity':

.... ...

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/session_server_ssh.c:1497: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_bind_accept_fd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/session_server_ssh.c:1498: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_get_error'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/session_server_ssh.c:1500: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_bind_free'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/session_server_ssh.c:1503: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_bind_free'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/session_server_ssh.c:1505: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_set_blocking'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/session_server_ssh.c:1511: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_handle_key_exchange'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/session_server_ssh.c:1525: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_get_error'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/session_server_ssh.c:1540: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_execute_message_callbacks'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: /g/Programming/netconf/libnetconf2/src/session_server_ssh.c:1541: undefined reference to `__imp_ssh_get_error'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/build.make:276: msys-netconf2-2.dll] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/netconf2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

4. Check the `/usr/lib/libssh.dll.a` file, the undefined functions exists in it:

```
$ objdump -t /usr/lib/libssh.dll.a | grep __
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_string_to_char
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_string_new
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_string_len
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_string_from_char
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_string_free
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_string_fill
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_string_data
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_string_copy
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_string_burn
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_write_knownhost
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_version
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_try_publickey
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_publickey_auto
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_publickey
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_pubkey
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_privatekey_file
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_password
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_offer_pubkey
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_none
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_list
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_kbdint_setanswer
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_kbdint_getprompt
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_kbdint_getnprompts
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_kbdint_getnanswers
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_kbdint_getname
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_kbdint_getinstruction
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_kbdint_getanswer
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_kbdint
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_gssapi
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_autopubkey
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_agent_pubkey
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_userauth_agent
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_try_publickey_from_file
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_threads_set_callbacks
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_threads_get_pthread
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_threads_get_noop
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_threads_get_default
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_string_to_char
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_string_new
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_string_len
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_string_get_char
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_string_from_char
```

```
$ objdump -t /usr/lib/libssh.dll.a | grep __imp_ssh_bind_free
[  6](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000000 __imp_ssh_bind_free
```

Those are all information I can find, could someone have the same issue with msys2 (for pure linux, like CentOS, there is no such issue)?

Comment: As the name of variable `LIBSSH_LIBRARIES` denotes, it is the list of **libraries**, that is **files**, but you attempt to use **directory** (`/usr/lib`) for initialize that variable. Instead, try to set `LIBSSH_LIBRARY` variable to the `/usr/lib/libssh.dll.a`. BTW, the script which searched for libssh is shipped with libnetconf2 project: https://github.com/CESNET/libnetconf2/blob/master/CMakeModules/FindLibSSH.cmake. So it is definitely not a problem with libssh.

Comment: Big thanks. You are right, I missed the `libssh.dll.a`. I have made a workaround by appending `/usr/lib/libssh.dll.a` to gcc by manual to pass the linker. However your solution is better than me and is a nice/common solution.